# How to put Graphic Abstract and Highlights on the first page of cas-dc document class?

Tags: environments, document-classes, overleaf, els-cas

The [cas-dc template](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates) puts graphicalabstract and highlights environments on the first two pages of an article:

[image: Graphical abstract]
[image: Highlights]

Is there a way to define environments like Article Info or Abstract and reproduce the example below? I could not find a template that locates them on the title page like below:
[image: Example article]

Comment: The whole highlights thing is confusing me. I uploaded a separate word document as stated here - https://www.elsevier.com/authors/tools-and-resources/highlights - which also says they're not for editorial consideration and are required later in the process. But the I received a comment back from the editor asking for highlights

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately not. We did not put graphical abstract to that article in the end. You may send the image separately (there is a separate category for graphical abstracts when you add the attachments). Maybe the journal then can do it for you.